# Managing docker-compose override files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We are developing a small project consisting of a mongodb, java backend and express-js based front-end. We've chose `docker-compose` as a deployment tool for all but production uses and so far it's been fairly good with one exception.

Currently, we use it for:

- running local dev cluster;
- running integration tests (with some tweaks and extra dependencies);
- preparing environment for load testing (with more tweaks);
- running staging/demo environment on a separate cloud machine.

To handle all those various tweaks per environment we've deduced a set of docker-compose files: `docker-compose.yml`, `d-c.override.yml`, `d-c.test.yml`, `d-c.load.yml` and `d-c.demo.yml` (`docker-compose` replaced with `d-c` for brevity).

This makes us use enourmously long command-line invocations to do anything except for basic tasks. For example:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml up -d --build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml exec test_container ./do_tests.sh
```

And it goes worse.

So far we've got couple ideas about improving that:

1. use full docker-compose files instead of partial to save up typing -- but extra maintenance when app structure changes / extra parameters are introduced;
2. (variation of the former) use `extends` for services and minimize the copy-paste (but adds extra complexity);
3. store all those lengthy commands in a `Makefile` (or a bash script). Ease of use, but feels like sweeping complexity under the rug;
4. (variation of the former) develop docker-compose plugin / own tooling -- may be more explicit in handling our needs, but extra maintenance and deployment complexity.

All of those ideas have their drawbacks -- I wonder what are proper solutions for that and what tools already exist.

Comment: Same here, we have splitted them into seperate folders.. keep it simple ;) cd stage / docker-compose up :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think 3 sounds like a good solution. It's not "hiding complexity", it's just automating a repetitive task (typing long command lines).

A Makefile would work, but you might also be interested in [dobi](http://dnephin.github.io/dobi/) (disclaimer: I am the author of this tool). `dobi` allows you to define all your project tasks in a yaml file, including running Compose with different files and project name. An example config for your project might look something like this

```
compose=dev:
  files: [docker-compose.yaml, d-c.override.yml]

compose=test:
  files: [docker-compose.yaml, d-c.test.yml]

compose=load:
  files: [docker-compose.yaml, d-c.load.yml]
```

Then you can run a task with `dobi dev`, etc.

You might even find that some of the one-off tasks can be moved to the dobi config, removing the need to have extra compose overrides.